# Non-group-by columns in aggregate query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have a table with three columns: `c1`, `c2`, and `c3`. I want to get, within each `c1`, the maximum value of `c2` and the value of `c3` of the row that contains the maximum value.

Here's an example. Say `MyTable` contains the following records:

```
c1   c2   c3
---  ---  ---
1    32   12
1    27   15
1    12   21
2    23   33
2    36   49
3    48   17
3    21   50
3    7    25
```

Then my query should return

```
c1   MAX(c2)  c3
---  -------  ---
1    32       12
2    36       49
3    48       17
```

But when I query

```
SELECT c1, MAX(c2), c3 FROM MyTable GROUP BY c1
```

I get the error:

```
Column 'MyTable.c3' is invalid in the select list because it is not 
contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

How can I fix this query? I have tried sub-queries, joins, etc. to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of `CASE` and `OVER()` clause.

```
DECLARE 
    @MyTable TABLE(c1 INT, c2 INT, c3 INT)

INSERT INTO @MyTable 
VALUES
(1,    32 ,  12),
(1,    27 ,  15),
(1,    12 ,  21),
(2,    23 ,  33),
(2,    36 ,  49),
(3,    48 ,  17),
(3,    21 ,  50),
(3,    7  ,  25)


SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT   
        c1
    ,   MAX(c2) OVER(PARTITION BY c1) c2
    ,   CASE WHEN c2 = MAX(c2) OVER(PARTITION BY c1) THEN c3 ELSE NULL END c3
    FROM @MyTable
) D
WHERE 
    c3 IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

I think a correlated subquery in `where` is a simple solution:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.col2 = (select max(t2.col2) from t t2 where t2.col1 = t.col1);
```

This often has very good performance characteristics.  The more traditional solution uses `row_number(`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col2 desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you have a separate separate table of col1 values, then `apply` can also have good performance:

```
select t.*
from table_col1 c1 cross apply
     (select top (1) t.*
      from t 
      where t.col1 = c1.col1
      order by t.col2 desc
     ) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
SELECT a.c1, a.c2, a.c3 
FROM
MyTable a
INNER JOIN
(SELECT c1, MAX(c2) as 'max_c2' FROM MyTable GROUP BY c1) b
ON
a.c1 = b.c1
AND
a.c2 = b.max_c2
```